# Changing Chapter colors in r bookdown (pdf output)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

In the regular bookdown format, every chapter is started with a bold:

**Chapter 1**

**Title of chapter**

I am trying to change the color of "Chapter 1" to a deep grey, instead of black. I am completely new to LaTeX, but have pieced some code together based on other Stackoverflow questions, to customize colors. I created a `mystyles.sty` file which consists of:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{battleshipgrey}{rgb}{0.52, 0.52, 0.51}
\titleformat{\thechapter}
{\color{battleshipgrey}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{battleshipgrey}\chapter}{1em}{}
```

My YAML header is:

```
title: "My Title"
author: "Me"
date: ""
output: pdf_document
bibliography: [bib.bib]
documentclass: book
geometry: left=4cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm
link-citations: yes
classoption: openany
biblio-style: apalike
subparagraph: true
```

And I have an _output.yml with the following code:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: mystyles.sty
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: no
mainfont: Bookman
```

What am I misspecifying in my `mystyles.sty` document? Currently, nothing is being changed in color. I have tried specifying:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\color{battleshipgrey}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{battleshipgrey}\thechapter}{1em}{}
```

But this colours the Chapter number and title grey, but the format of the Chapter title changes to:

**1 Title of chapter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ekstroem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4288660/ekstroem) put me on the right track to use the sectsty package. I tried using `\chapternumberfont` from the sectsty package, which didn't work. I think Bookdown doesn't set the name for the chapter number to this particular name. I found a workaround that worked, by using setting the entire chapter to grey, and then setting the chapter title to black:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\definecolor{battleshipgrey}{rgb}{0.52, 0.52, 0.51}
\chapterfont{\color{battleshipgrey}}
\chaptertitlefont{\color{black}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following which uses the `xcolor` and `sectsty` packages in `mystyes.sty`:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\definecolor{battleshipgrey}{rgb}{0.52, 0.52, 0.51}
\chapterfont{\color{battleshipgrey}}  % sets colour of chapters
```

That seems to work at my end anyway and will produce chapter titles in gray without numbers.

Comment: So sorry for my late reply, I hadn't been able to work on this project for some time. For me this sets both "Chapter 1" and "Chapter title" in gray, where I only want it to work for the "Chapter 1" part. I will look into the sectsty package to see if I can figure it out further.

Comment: I tried using `\chapternumberfont` from the sectsty package, which didn't work. I think Bookdown doesn't set the name for the chapter number to this particular name. I found a workaround that worked, by using setting the entire chapter to grey, and then setting the chapter title to black: `\chapterfont{\color{battleshipgrey}}
\chaptertitlefont{\color{black}}`